# Colorful matching

Tags: combinatorics

The cells of an $n$ by $n$ grid are colored by $n$ colors, such that every $n$ cells have a different color. See example below for $n=3$:

[image]

Is it always possible to pick $n$ cells such that there is a single cell in each row, column and color?

Comment: I don't understand what does every n cells means?

Comment: I agree with Aqua, it’s not clear what the condition on your coloring is. Do you just mean that each color appears $n$ times, or something stronger than that?

Comment: Perhaps "every $n$ cells ..." means any row, any column, and any diagonal contains more than one color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact condition on your coloring is not clear, but I suspect that you should be able to construct a counterexample based on the group table of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (interpreting the integers mod $4$ as colors) using a result of Maillet which implies that this group table has no transversal: that is, Maillet's result says you can't get the matching you want for the coloring

> [image: group table for Z4]

(please pardon the hasty MSPaint diagram) and permuting rows and columns to fit your condition (perhaps the monochromatic antidiagonal of 3's is forbidden?) should preserve the property that there is no transversal.

If this example does not work, I suspect you should be able to get a counterexample using some other result about Latin squares that fail to have transversals; [this talk by Wanless](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~loops07/presentations/wanless.pdf) seems to be a decent survey of such results.

Comment: Thanks, this is the counter-example I was looking for.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi you're welcome. Note also that if there *isn't* actually any kind of restriction on the diagonal (if you really just want "every color appears $n$ times") then the $2 \times 2$ checkerboard is a smaller counterexample.